# .screenrc bindkey for Cmd-Right on MAC

Tags: linux, command-line, gnu-screen

I'm trying to bind <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Right</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd> to next and previous in my screenrc.

I've seen entries like the following but I do not know how to find the keycode for <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Right</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd>. Is there a utility I can use somewhere?

```
bindkey "^[[1;5C"    next  # Ctrl-Right
bindkey "^[[1;5D"    prev  # Ctrl-Left

bindkey "^[[27;5;9~" next  # Ctrl-Tab
bindkey "^[[27;6;9~" prev  # Ctrl-Shift-Tab
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use xev and then put the result into .Xmodmap file. Take a look to [this](http://cweiske.de/howto/xmodmap/allinone.html) HOWTO.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old post, but I figured I would share this in anyway...  there is a solution for this if you use iTerm2.  You can map keys in iTerm2 preferences either at a global level or a profile level.  I configured my CMD-left/right to send the same escape codes as CTRL-left/right.  Then the .screenrc key bindings you are already using will work.

Answer (score -3):

Just use `cat` in a terminal. Then all keycodes will be posted to stdout!